# regex to match MINUS with spaces

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have to define a regex such that :

```
r'[ - &]'
```

so, here `spaceMINUSspace` should be taken as one thing.

for eg:

it should match string like: `foo - bar` and `foo&bar`. It should not match something like this `foo-bar`.

Please suggest how do i do this.

Comment: does it only have to match `foo - bar` and `foo&bar`? Or anything that is two words that doesn't have a `-` in between without spaces.

Comment: words can be any words. If it's separated by spaceMINUSspace it should get matched. If its' separated by & it should match.

Comment: If it's imperative that the match include the words, would you mind editing the language in the question to reflect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `re.match`, with the following pattern:

```
.*\w+(?:( - )|&)\w.*
```

This says to match two words, separated by either `-` or `&`.  Here is a code snippet:

```
line = "foo - bar"
match = re.match( r'.*\w+(?:( - )|&)\w.*', line, re.M|re.I)

if match:
    print "Found this match: ", match.group()
```

Or, as @Sean pointed out, we could use `re.search`:

```
line = "foo - bar"
pattern = re.compile(r'\w+(?:( - )|&)\w')

if pattern.search(line):
    print "Found this match: ", line
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `.*\w+`? Is `\w+` not enough?

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge It looks like the `re.match` API insists on the pattern matching the entire string ([see here](http://rextester.com/OXSL72663)).  So I add `.*` on both ends to ensure that everything gets matched.

Comment: I see. It seems to match [from the beginning of the string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), so `.*\w+(?:( - )|&)\w` would work as well (though not be as useful). Why not use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) with `\w+(?:( - )|&)\w` then? [demo](http://rextester.com/LGMFT31743)